# ruby on rails: export and merge databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, merge, export

I am currently working on a ruby on rails project with a MySQL-Database.

Is there a way to export the database and merge it with another one?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean something more than just `mysqldump` from one DB and loading it into another? Do you need to merge tables or alter update schemas? What exactly?

Comment: Let's say there are two systems running the same rails-project over a longer period of time and now I want system B to merge it's data with system A. Since both system had the same tables they don't need to exchange the schemas.

It would be nice for the user to do the export/import directly in rails from something like an admin-area page.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but it might help.

http://dominikgrabiec.com/111-simple-dataset-exportimport-for-rails/

Comment: updated link is - http://www.dominikgrabiec.com/2009/simple-dataset-exportimport-for-rails/